# How to protect XHTML files from editing

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, xhtml

I am developing a JSF application and the archive (war) will be given to multiple customers and will be separately deployed on their own Tomcat servers. This is just a front end application and it uses web services to communicate with a remote server.

In my JSF application, some tabs and panels are conditionally rendered according to the `ORG_ID` and `Roles` of the logged in user. All these restrictions are written in `.xhtml` pages as ELs:

```
<rich:tab header="Registration" rendered="#{permissionController.hasSuperRole()}"/>
```

Since this application is deployed in customers premises, they can edit the `.xhtml` files and remove these restrictions. Is there a way to overcome this issue by encrypting xhtml files, checking last modified date...?

Comment: You can repeat checking in action methods. It is Java code and cannot be changed on client side. Maybe it is not the best suggestion, but at least it will work as prevention against some restricted operations.

Comment: It would not be easy, but you can create own version of jsf-impl. I suppose that such solution would require extending `com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.Compiler` with additional implementation of checking integrity of xhtml files.

Comment: 'Just' do additional authorization in the webservices...

Answer (score 0):

This issue is totally not related to java jsf or (x)html. It is the generic issue that you should never trust the client (like you never should in e.g. a webapplication where a user can manipulate the html/javascript in the browser)

**Solution**: Just do additional authorization in the webservices.